# can a service like isup.me be duplicated on the system for self?

Tags: shell, networking, ip, dynamic-dns

The Internet or Web as I understand it runs on variety of servers. The browser is the client which gives a URI or URL which tries to go through varied ways to connect to the web-page and render the web-page. But sometimes, there is a failure. Sometimes, when it fails you get a 404 or some other service number but sometimes you just get a connection timed out message. In either of the scenarios, people take the use of isup.me web service. If the site is up, then you try either changing browsers, using tor or some other way to access that web-site.

My question are two-fold :-

a. Does anybody have any idea how the isup.me web-service works ?

The only way I see it happening is if it's either at an [Internet Exchange Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_exchange_point) (IXP) or near the [backbone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_backbone) .

So while it may not be possible to emulate this service totally, is there some sort of poor man's method to do a similar kind of service for self.

The only way I see is having multiple service providers (ISP's) and hoping that all of them don't take the same path. Not a very effective methodology or is there any other ways ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about UNIX or Linux; perhaps superuser.com would be a better fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done on a distributed system but that's not likely the case as it would make it more expensive and complicated to run.  Even with a distributed system, you could never have enough servers to be perfectly aware of specific network outages.  Furthermore, your total load and bandwidth would always be in function of the number of servers, which is very inefficient.

It's most likely an extremely simple script that tries to open the site you ask from their server and if it gets any error returned, then it says the site is down.  A simple version of such a script can be done in 15 minutes or less by an experienced programmer.